# Pointers in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Pointers can be still used in pascal and i think they may preserve it until delphi is alive.

Even though i have used pointer when i am learning pascal. I still can't understand the real use of pointers, I manage to do all my delphi programs without it.(by some other ways)

what is the real use of pointers. And I am asking for real world usage, and can we manage to do anything without pointers.

Comment: Pointers allow you to take references to things. Imagine how you would implement a linked list without references.

Comment: Why the votes to close? This is an actual question related to programming, IMO.

Comment: @Ken Close votes because the Q is far too general. It could be turned into a good Q. It's probably a dupe too if anyone searched!

Comment: Pointers are pretty much required for every single interesting thing you can program on a computer. They're the key to implementing most data structures (including the humble linked list). They're behind every single Object (Forms, Components), they're behind every Event you use and they make virtual methods work (vtable). This is not the place to discuss such a broad subject: please read the [Wikipedia page on Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)), try implementing some interesting data structures and ask more specific questions if you get in trouble. Voting to close.

Comment: @Cosmin But there are languages that don't have explicit pointers.

Comment: @David, they don't use *explicit* pointers, they do use pointers. The only difference is, they don't trust the user to manage there own memory.

Comment: @David and @Cosmin, I understand your reasoning, although I don't agree (and am not adding a vote to close). The question might be a little broad, but it was specific enough to garner some answers. "What use are pointers in modern Object Pascal?" seems like a reasonable question. But that's my opinion. :)

Comment: I don't think it is a great question, because 1) pointers aren't specific to Delphi, and most Delphi applications are in fact not Delphi-specific, and 2) to learn something as basic as this, one should probably read a good book about it. In addition, pointers aren't used by beginners (at least not Delphi beginners). When the beginner becomes more sophisticated, he/she will naturally begin to need things like pointers. Also, the real "need" for pointers is to some extent subjective, because in many (most, or all?) cases you can redesign your algorithms to work without them. And this is a dupli.

Comment: @Andreas, I didn't say it was a *great* question; just a reasonable one. (And I notice that even though you didn't like it, you posted an answer. <g>)

Comment: @Ken: Yes, I saw that my "favourite" application of (explicit) pointers wasn't mentioned. I actually did vote to close. Indeed, if nothing else, this got to be a duplicate (since it isn't Delphi-specific, after all). Anyhow, I agree that I did hesitate before hitting the close button.

Comment: I must say, I'm surprised to find that I appear to be the only person here to believe that it is possible to program without explicit use of pointers. That was, to my mind, the key question asked here.

Comment: @David: Above, I wrote "Also, the real 'need' for pointers is to some extent subjective, because in many (most, or all?) cases you can redesign your algorithms to work without them." (Of course, I am talking about the explicit pointers, not object variables etc.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the pointers contain the address of a memory location, because that  are present everywhere.  each variable which you declare,  even the code which you write can be accessed using a pointer, the pointers is one of the most essential elements in Win32 programming,  you must read this great article from Rudy Velthuis [`Addressing pointers`](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html) to understand the  pointers usage.

Comment: +1 for the link to Rudy's article. A great read for this question's author.

Comment: The link is currently: http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-pointers.html

Comment: Rudy's article is a gem!

Answer (score 13):

You use pointers a lot more often than you think you do in Delphi. The compiler just hides it.

```
var
  SL: TStringList; 
...
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  // SL is now a pointer to an instance of the TStringList class.
  // You don't know it because the compiler handles dereferencing
  // it, so you don't have to use SL^ . You can just use the var.
  SL.Add('This is a string');
```

A string is also a pointer to a block of memory that stores the string. (It actually stores more than that, but...)

So are instances of records, PChars (which is a pointer to a character array, basically), and tons of other things you use every day. There are lots of pointers that aren't called Pointer. :)

Comment: There are languages that don't explicitly use pointers. I'm thinking of Java and C# (not using unsafe).

Answer (score 5):

To understand what pointers might be used for in modern day Delphi, one needs to understand how pointers have been historically used and how Delphi uses pointers behind the scenes.

## Pointers to code

One can have a pointer to a piece of code. This can be used for the intuitive thing (parameterizing some algorithm with the functions it needs to call; example: `TObjectList.Sort` takes a function pointer as a parameter). Modern Delphi uses pointers-to-code to implement the following (without going into details):

- Virtual Method Tables; We can't have OOP without VMT's
- Interfaces
- Events and anonymous methods.

Those are all very powerful methods of avoiding raw pointers to code, indeed there's very little need for raw code pointers today.

## Pointers to data

Everybody learned pointers using the Linked Lists. Pointers are essential in the implementation most non-trivial data structures; In fact it's hard to name a useful data structure that's not implemented using pointers.

Delphi gives lots of grate abstractions for data pointers, so we can work without ever touching an pointer. We have Objects (class instances) and good implementations for most data structures (`string`, TObjectList, dynamic arrays).

## When do we use Pointers?

We essentially use pointers to implement more of the grate stuff that Delphi provides for us. I can give examples of what I've used pointers for, but I find it more interesting to give examples of what others have used pointers for:

- **TVirtualTree**: Makes good use of pointers to data.
- [Pascal Script for Delphi](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx): Makes extensive use of raw pointers to code!

Comment: grate?? Slight spelling mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with a definition, taken from Wikipedia:

> A pointer is a programming language
>   data type whose value refers directly
>   to (or "points to") another value
>   stored elsewhere in the computer
>   memory using its address.

All computers address memory and to do so the machine language that they execute must do so using pointers.

However, high level languages do not need to include pointers explicitly. Some examples of those that do not are LISP, Java, C#, Perl, Python, but there are many more.

I'm interpreting your question to be why languages support explicit pointer use, since all languages use pointers implicitly.

Delphi descends from Pascal which is a rather primitive language when viewed from the 21<sup>st</sup> century. Pascal pointers are the only way to use references. In modern Pascal derivatives, e.g. Delphi, have many types of data that are reference based, but implicitly so. For example I'm thinking of strings, object instances, interfaces and so on.

It is perfectly possible to write any program in Delphi without resorting to explicit pointers. The modern trend away from explicit pointers is down to the observation that explicit pointer code is more prone to errors than the alternatives.

I don't think there's any real reason to carry on using explicit pointer code in Delphi. Perhaps very time critical algorithms may push you that way, but I'm really struggling to think of anything that is significantly better implemented with pointers than with the alternatives.

Personally I avoid using explicit pointers wherever feasible. It generally makes code easier to write, verify and maintain, in my experience.

Comment: Python has pointers: [Python Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/ctypes-pointers.html). Then again Python has everything.

Comment: That's not Python, that's ctypes which is not part of the language. I love ctypes, but it's not Python per se.

Comment: I have a hard time differentiating Python from it's libraries. I never wrote an Python script that doesn't start with `import ...`, but you're right, that's ctypes. +1.

Comment: @Cosmin You never wrote a Delphi program that didn't start `uses` either!

Comment: Yes C/C++ are primitive languages because they have pointers :) CPUs understand pointers, that's why any language designed when programmers had an idea of how a computer works has pointers. It's simply low-level memory access, nothing more. IMHO languages for primitives **don't** have pointers. They are designed for primitive programmers who will fire into theit feet if you give them pointers. The language has to protect them from playing with those dangerous pointers, or they will set their code afire :)

Comment: @Idsandon Pascal is primitive. Delphi is not. Python is not primitive. C# is not primitive. I like each language for tasks at which it is suited. One language is not enough.

Comment: IMHO Delphi **is** Pascal. If Wirth didn't upgrade Pascal itself evolving it into Modula and Oberon I do not care. Others upgraded it. For a long time it was Borland *Pascal*, then they tried to rename it Object Pascal but there was copyright issue. Then they tried Delphi but it just added confusion. FreePascal is named Pascal, is it primitive too because it's named *Pascal*? Is C primitive then? Why Python and C# are not primitive? What they offer more than any recent implementation of Pascal? A way to sandbox the developer to hire cheaper ones instead of skilled ones?

Comment: @Idsandon Well, my answer made it quite clear that when I referred to Pascal I was talking about Pascal of the 70's. Just read my answer with that interpretation.

Comment: "[no] real reason to carry on using explicit pointer code" - I agree.

Answer (score 2):

1)  Classes are pointers.  Strings are pointers.  The compiler pretty much hides this from you but you do need to understand this when debugging.

2)  Any sort of tree structure needs pointers.

Comment: Do you mean classes? I think you mean objects.

Comment: We could play a game: Name a data structure that **doesn't** use pointers. I can think of: Array, BitField, Records/Structures.

Comment: Neither classes nor objects are pointers. The variables we use to *refer to* classes and objects are implemented as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I use a lot of custom data structures in my programs (for instance, in my own scripting language /interpreter/, where I store the structures, or "records", used in this language - these can contain other records and the nesting is unrestricted). I do this at the very lowest level, namely, I allocate a number of bytes on the heap, and then I read, parse, and write to these completely manually. To this end, I need pointers to point to the bytes in the allocated blocks. Typically, the blocks consists of "records" that reference each other in some ways. In addition, many of these structures can be written to file (that is, I have also designed my own binary file formats), simply by copying from the heap (in RAM) to the disk byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers (memory addresses) are a basic CPU type to access memory. Whatever language you use to write an application, when it comes to the CPU it has to use "pointers" to work.
Thereby they are a low-level type which allows a huge degree of versatility, at the price of a somewhat more complex management and the risk of accessing or writing the wrong memory if not used correctly.
You could let a language translate your data to pointers and memory buffers, or use pointers directly if the language allows for it. Being able to do it allows for direct and optimized memory access and management.

Comment: Why downvoting? Please show what's wrong there... if you are able to explain it.

Comment: @Idsandon: At least you aren't alone... +1

Answer (score 1):

I thought I could add my salt to the soup, but the answers above say it mostly all. There's one more thing though. I remember being **scared** when I saw all those referencing and dereferencing operators (in different languages) and all the magic that was done with pointers. I didn't dare to look the devil in the eye for YEARS. I preferred to ineffectively copy data instead of going down the pointer path.

Today though, I do love pointers. Working with pointers makes you aware of what happens under the hood. And it makes you aware of the memory you are playing with (responsibly). Practically it allows you to code more effitiently and consciously! Last but not least it turns out to be quite fun to play with such simple but powerful toys.